# Link font size does not change

Tags: html, css, asp.net

```css
.big-font {
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<link href="~/css/websitecss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
<a class="btn btn-secondary flex-fill big-font">@item</a>
```

No matter what I pick, font size is always the same (relatively small). I suppose bootstrap might be overwriting it.

Comment: @wazz problem solved.

Comment: Sry moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it might be Bootstrap. Always add `!important` to your CSS if using with a Bootstrap class.

Answer (score 1):

Using `!important` always is not a good practice. Instead you can chain the classes or follow CSS precedence rule.

Chaining example given below.

```css
.btn.big-font {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a class="btn btn-secondary flex-fill big-font">@item</a>
```